# Laravel8 Has One Of Many

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-8, relation

I'm relatively new to Laravel 8 and I have problem figuring what should I do when I need a relationship Has One Of Many
In the doc of Laravel 8 It's not very well documented.

My User can have only one Job.
I have a tables Jobs where I list all available Job
{ id, name, timestamps }

Should I create a job_id in the User table to store the id of the Job
or
Should I use a Many To Many with a job_user table

Is there a better way to create a Has One of Many relationship.

Comment: If I understand your question properly you just need `hasOne()` relationship with a foreign key in one of the tables.

Comment: in the user table you need to store job_id and use hasOne() relationship

Comment: @PalakJadav If I understand right in the user table I add job_id and in the user model I create a hasone relationship. Will I be able to access the job->name from the User model

Comment: yes you will @MathieuB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you relation is quite simple:

Job hasMany users

User hasOne Job

so, in the users table you should add job_id and link it to jobs table.

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->unsignedBigInteger('job_id');
               $table->foreign("job_id")->references('id')->on('jobs');
        });
    }
```

and make sure this migration comes after creating both users and jobs tables.

according to Laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many),the relation should be setup like this:

in User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Job', "user_id");
    }
}
```

and for Job model:

```
class Job extends Model
{
   public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', "user_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sound good but this also need a Pivot Table or not.

Comment: pivot table is needed only for many to many relations

Comment: since User can have only one Job, there is no many to many

Comment: In the User Modal in the Job function I user "hasOne" instead of belongsTo. Any tought on this. return $this->hasOne(Job::class,'id','job_id');